# how to remove keyboard when user click any where in window?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

can you please tell me how to hide the  keyboard in IOS when user click anywhere in window.I used blur() on button click it work but when i used in view it not work..:(

I check if user click any where other than textfield it hide the keyboard my my logic fail..:(

Here is my code..

```
//FirstView Component Constructor
function FirstView() {
    //create object instance, a parasitic subclass of Observable
    var self = Ti.UI.createView({
        layout:"vertical"
    });


        var self1 = Ti.UI.createView({
        layout:"horizontal",
        top:20,
        height:Ti.UI.SIZE
    });



        var self2 = Ti.UI.createView({
        layout:"horizontal",
        top:10,
        height:Ti.UI.SIZE
    });



    //label using localization-ready strings from <app dir>/i18n/en/strings.xml

        var nameLabel=Ti.UI.createLabel({

        text:"Name",

        left:15,
        width:100,
        height:35
    });




    var nameTextField=Ti.UI.createTextField({

    height:35,
    width:140,
    borderStyle:Titanium.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED       
    });

        self1.add(nameLabel);
        self1.add(nameTextField);
            self.add(self1);

    var passwordLabel=Ti.UI.createLabel({

        text:"Password",

        left:15,
        width:100,
        height:35
    });




    var passwordTextField=Ti.UI.createTextField({

    height:35,
    width:140,
    passwordMask:true,
    borderStyle:Titanium.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED       
    });


    var loginButton =Ti.UI.createButton({

        title:"LOGIN",
        top: 120,
        width:200,
        height:40

    });


    loginButton.addEventListener('click',function(e){
        passwordTextField.blur();
        nameTextField.blur();

    });

    self2.add(passwordLabel);
    self2.add(passwordTextField);// self.backgroundImage="http://bluebackground.com/__oneclick_uploads/2008/04/blue_background_03.jpg";

    self.add(self2);
    self.add(loginButton);

    self.addEventListener('click',function(e){

        if(e.source != [Ti.UI.TextField]){
            alert("window click");
        passwordTextField.blur();
        nameTextField.blur();

}

    });
    return self;
}

module.exports = FirstView;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you could precise the Titanium version you're using.

But as far as I know, with the version 3.1.1.GA, you can do like this :

```
if (e.source != '[object TiUITextField]') {
```

instead of :

```
if(e.source != [Ti.UI.TextField]){
```

For me, it works just fine :

- click on textfields : open the keyboard
- click somewhere else : close the keyboard

And you don't even need the event listener on your button anymore.

Comment: The string '[object TiUITextField]' might be changed in future SDK. Should check for all text field object.  if(e.source != nameTextField && e.source != passwordTextField)